# recreating Default Web Site renders other sites inaccessible

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7, domain

After recreating a previously deleted Default Web Site in IIS 7, the other sites are no longer accessible by host header (all on :80).

Assuming the local domain is called `company.local` and having both an A host record for `webserver.company.local` and CNAME aliases for `site_1.webserver.company.local` through `site_n.webserver.company.local`, ping replies from the sites now state hosts cannot be found.

`http://webserver` does show the IIS welcome page.

What obvious steps might I have forgotten to take after recreating the Default Web Site?

Comment: if you can not ping the hosts then it is not IIS at fault.

Comment: @rob ok makes sense, but nothing has changed on the DNS

Comment: try manually setting them up in the hosts file to show IIS does work correctly.

Comment: @rob yes that works

Comment: cool, IIS is off the hook, now you can have fun tracking down your dns issue.